# How do splinter groups get popular, when they deal with the same content as the parent group?

Tags: reddit

#### Is there a term for such splinter groups? Any tips on how to grow in subscribers and numbers?*(=

I am referring to SubReddits like [r/wallstreetbets2](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets2) that splintered off [r/wallstreetbets](https://old.reddit.com/r/wallstreetbets), and [r/antinatalism2](https://old.reddit.com/r/antinatalism2) off [r/antinatalism](https://old.reddit.com/r/antinatalism2). These splinter groups have a hard time blowing up mainstream, because the parent captures the market and gets  the attention.

Of all the xplainlikeim# or eli# SubReddits, **I have long wondered why [r/explainlikeimfive](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive) (at 21.4 million subscribers) has been  the only one that popularized?**

- [r/ExplainLikeImThree](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimthree)
- [r/ExplainMeLikeImSix](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainmelikeimsix)
- [r/ExplainLikeImSeven](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimseven)
- [r/ExplainLikeImTen](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimten)
- [r/ELI9](https://old.reddit.com/r/ELI9)

Comment: Welcome to [communitybuilding.se]! I'm not sure if this type of question is [on topic here](/help/on-topic) (though I would have a hard time thinking of the right SE site to post it).

Answer (score 2):

Some psychologist or sociologist must have studied and researched this kind of question? Here are my thoughts, as nobody has answered this. Many groups splinter a result of a disagreement with the parent group.

Isn't  [r/explainlikeimfive](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimfive) one of the earliest Reddits? Anyone know their commencement date?

#### These factors influence a community's growth.

- community settings and design
- the mods, and their dedication seeding content and advertising. Many Reddits lack moderators as you can see from [r/AdoptAReddit](https://oldreddit.com/r/adoptareddit/), [r/ReClassified](https://old.reddit.com/r/reclassified) and [r/RedditRequest](https://old.reddit.com/r/redditrequest).
- timing
- rules. ease of use
- Do they trend? Does Reddit recommend them to users? Do Redditors recommend them to their contacts?

#### And why don't you add these to your list?

- [r/explainlikeimhuman](https://old.reddit.com/r/explainlikeimhuman)
- [r/eli7](https://old.reddit.com/r/eli7)